# Find the height of a bezier curve in canvas

Tags: canvas, bezier

I am trying to create a simple rounded top to a rectangle.  I was able to use the `bezierCurveTo` method to create the cap, but I had to play around with the control point's y values to get the correct height of the curve.  If I have the width and I know the height that I want the curve to pass through is their a formula to find the control point's y values?  the function I have right now is

```
c.moveTo(130,55);
c.bezierCurveTo(130,-18,0,-18,0,55);
```

-18 is what I had to set the y values to to get the curve to approximately pass through y = 0.

Comment: Do you need to use the bezier curve and all its power, or would a simple circular `arcTo` give you what you need?

Comment: @Phrogz Technically no, but I like how the bezier curve is straighter on the sides leading into the straight section.  As I mentioned I have something that works I just wondered what the formula would be if I had this problem again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple answer for this constrained version of Bezier curves.  Taking the definition of a cubic Bezier curve from wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), and solving for the mid point along the curve (t=0.5), the minimum value of y will be:

```
1/4 Ymax + 3/4 Ymin
```

(Ymax being the y value of the start and end points and Ymin being the y value of the two control points).
Or, for the midpoint to be 0,

```
Ymin = -1/3 Ymax.
```

So, since you have Ymax = 55, Ymin has to be -1/3*55 = -18.333.. -- which is why 18 worked in your example.

Comment: I'd almost forgotten about this question thanks for the answer.